# File.list only returning Id and name

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am doing a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) in the google drive api

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?access_token=XXXX
```

This is working fine but its only returning four fields for each of the files in the list

```
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "1x8-vD-XiXEEA5Spf3qp8x2wltablGF22Lpwup8VtxNY",
"name": "Experts Activity Dump go/ExpertsActivities",
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
```

The documentation states that it should be returning a full [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) for each file but its not.

The only thing i have been able to do is to do a file.get on each of the files to get additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an old issue that appears to have been fixed now.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*&access_token=XXXX
```

by sending fields=* you can now see a full file.resorce response for each of the files in the list.  It is no longer necessary to do a file.get for each file.

That being said its probably a good idea to limit the fields to those you actually need

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour of the API. For reference, you may see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#fields) the explanation next to the "fields" parameter:

> The paths of the fields you want included in the response. **If not specified, the response includes a default set of fields specific to this method.** For development you can use the special value * to return all fields, but you'll achieve greater performance by only selecting the fields you need. For more information see the partial responses documentation.

For this api, the default fields are indeed kind, id, name and mimeType.

It is recommended that you limit the fields (using the aforementioned parameter) to the ones you need, as it will yield a considerable performance difference.